# NSFetchedResultsController only returning one section

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, sections

For some reason, my method call -numberOfSectionsInTableView always returns one section no matter what the data model looks like.

Here is some snippets of code from my TableVIewController.m. Feel free to ask for more if you need it

```
self.sortDesciptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"weaponData" ascending:YES];
self.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.sortDesciptor, nil];
self.sortSectionKey = @"weaponData";

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"number of sections:%lu",(unsigned long)[[_fetchedResultsController sections] count]);
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]    objectAtIndex:section];
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[sectionInfo numberOfObjects]);
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [[[sectionInfo objects] objectAtIndex:section] weaponData];
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    sTCAppDelegate *appDelegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context =[appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TargetData" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:0];

    if (self.sortMethod == 0){
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    }
    else{
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:self.sortDescriptors];
    }

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedRequestsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:self.sortSectionKey cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedRequestsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedRequestsController;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

In this example from my code, think about what would happen if I two "weaponData" objects in my "weaponData" entity. Say the first one is named Sniper Rifle and the second is named Assault Rifle. This should create two sections with one named Sniper Rifle and one named Assault Rifle.What actually happens is that I only get 1 section and it is named based off of whatever object entered the object context first.

Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: sectionKey = the key you use to determine the weapon type ?

Comment: Yes. The sortSectionKey is equal to the sortDescriptorKey. This can be shown because the app will at least show one section with a name of a weapon correctly. It just doesn't do more than 1 for some reason

Comment: is weaponData the attribute that has the weapon name in it ? So weapon data for object 1 = Sniper Rifle, weapon data for object 2 = Assault Rifle ?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct

Comment: When you load the fetch results controller, i.e. on line :  NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedRequestsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:self.sortSectionKey cacheName:nil]; 

Is the self.sortSectionKey name the string you want it to be?

Comment: Make sure you're actually setting:

    self.sortSectionKey = @"weaponData";

_before_ you make a call to your `fetchedResultsController` method.

Comment: yeah, that is the problem... when is the call to fetchedResultsController actually made?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a sort descriptor instead of a keyPath.  Just pass in @"weaponData" for the sectionNameKeyPath